# Using NSDate to find time spent in background

Tags: nsdate

I would like to be able to have a NSDate created when a button is pressed. Then, when the app enters sleep mode, and the user returns after a random amount of time, I compare the current time to the NSDate saved to find how much time to add to a NSTimer. So far, I have a created a NSDate in my button pressed method:

```
NSDate *test = [NSDate date];
```

I need help figuring out how to calculate the time since the NSDate in minutes and then put that info in a int. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// before sleeping
NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date];


// when waking up
NSTimeInterval elapsed = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];
```